# at: how to schedule a job to run at one second later?

Tags: linux, job-scheduling

I want to use the command "at" to schedule a job to run at one second (or minute/hour) later. If using "-t" option, then it involves with the hassle of getting the current time etc. Is there any easy way out?

But don't suggest me to use "sleep", because the current process will exit.

Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `at` program can take `now+` a time unit (e.g. `now+1minute`) as a timespec.  You won't get finer time resolution than one minute with `at`.

Comment: Feel free to take the "probably" out.  At doesn't handle smaller than a minute times.

Comment: "at ./hello.sh -t now+1" not working, :(